# How to solve ORO-CRM - The application is not configured properly (message consumers are not available). Please contact the system administrator

Tags: orocrm

After installing just logged out and logged in i am getting notification like **The application is not configured properly (message consumers are not available). Please contact the system administrator.** How to solve this?

**Note : Using Bitnami-ORO-CRM in Windows**

Comment: There is nothing about Magento - please remove extra tag

Comment: @SerhiiPolishchuk Kindly check with an updated post.

Comment: I'm personally using Linux host, and I never heard about Bitnami.
@zus you should ensure that consumers are run after your story

Comment: How can I check if consumer run or not? @serhii Polishuk

Comment: consumer is a separate php process in your system that run in background, you can find it in the list of processes (I'm use *htop* in my Linux servers).
You can use any amount of consumers, so run one more from console and follow the errors (if any)

Answer (score 1):

You should run message consumer as a background process. The easiest way to do so is:

```
bin/console oro:message-queue:consume --env=prod
```

See the installation guide reference https://oroinc.com/orocrm/doc/current/install-upgrade/installation-quick-start-dev/crm#configure-and-run-required-background-processes

**Update:**

Your error massage is about: "*You have a queue that are growing and nobody (no consumers) are handle it*"

Comment: I have work orocrm in windows localhost using Bitnami ORO-CRM, so that how can i run -> bin/console oro:message-queue:consume --env=prod